# Azure DevOps Server Invoke-RestMethod Error: No API version provided for the "PUT" request

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Based on this [PowerShell example](https://gist.github.com/tegaaa/e14820ccf7ea99ba2ef9d0c3cc180df4) from Etienne Tremblay I try to pass data to the Azure DevOps Server (2019.0.1) REST API.

In this example I would like to modify the description text of a project (just for test reasons):

```
# DEMO 5 Update an environement build variable
Write-Host "Demo 5"
$projects.value | ForEach-Object {
    $project = $_.name
    $buildManagementAreaId = "efc2f575-36ef-48e9-b672-0c6fb4a48ac5"
    $tfsBaseUrl = GetUrl -orgUrl $orgUrl -header $header -AreaId $buildManagementAreaId

    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0
    $relDefUrl = "$tfsBaseUrl$project/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.0"
    Write-Host "Requesting URL: $relDefUrl" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod $relDefUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
    $relDefs = $result.value

    if($relDefs.count -gt 0){
        Write-Host "$project $($relDefs.count) build def founds" -ForegroundColor Blue
        $relDefs | ForEach-Object {

            $relDef = $_
            $relDefExpanded = Invoke-RestMethod "$($relDef.url)?`$Expand=Environments&api-version=5.0" -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
            $relDefExpanded.project.description = "Hallo!!!"

            $body = $relDefExpanded | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 -Compress
            $body = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($body)

            #ERROR OCCURS HERE
            $updateResult = Invoke-RestMethod "$($relDef.url)?api-version=5.0" -Method Put -ContentType "application/json" -body $body -Headers $header 
            Write-host "Variable value after: $($updateResult.project.description)" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
    }
}
```

Hints:

- `$projects` get defined before in the script (demo1)
- the original script change a variable not a description (both versions don't work)

**The Error occurs on:**

```
$updateResult = Invoke-RestMethod "$($relDef.url)?api-version=5.0" -Method Put -ContentType "application/json" -body $body -Headers $header
```

**with the message:**

```
Invoke-RestMethod: {"$ id": "1", "innerException": null, "message": "No API version provided for the" PUT "request The version must either be part of the" Accept "header (eg
\ "application / json; api-version = 1.0 \") or as a query parameter (for example, "? api-version = 1.0")
. Will "," type name ":" Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssVersionNotSpecifiedException,
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi","typeKey":"VssVersionNotSpecifiedException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
In C:\Users\mkober\Desktop\Azure DevOps Console\WriteAPI.ps1:75 Zeichen:29
+ ... ateResult = Invoke-RestMethod "$($relDef.url)?api-version=5.0" -Metho ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

**Final URL:**

```
http://138.202.18.216:8070/Samples/19e02b27-74ab-40dd-a519-ece38fafa870/_apis/build/Definitions/11?revision=5?api-version=5.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to fix the url, change the `?` before the `api-version` to `&`:

```
?revision=5&api-version=5.0
```

The `revision` and the `api-version` is parameters, if you have only one parameter you use `?` but when you want to use more you need to append them with `&`.

Comment: you'r right the `Invoke-RestMethod` accept the fixed url. Thanks a lot! But the `$updateResult` do not take over the changes inside of the `$body`. The result after will be the same like before. Is it not possible to change the project description like that?

Comment: It should be possible. try to `$body = relDefExpanded | CovnertTo-Json -Depth 10` and remove the line after (`encoding etc.`)

Comment: without the `encoding` line `Invoke-RestMethod` throws an error: `Invoke-RestMethod: {"$ id": "1", "innerException": null, "message": "This request expects an object in the request body, but the specified data could not be deserialized.", "TypeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.RequestContentException,
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi "," TypeKey ":" Request Content Exception "," error code ": 0," eventId ": 3000}`

Comment: @MarTin this is wired, I success to update a build definition without the encoding.

Comment: I understand that. Unfortunately my whole work with azure devops is wired. I only run the example that I post from Etienne. Is it maybe possible to reproduce this example?

Comment: @MarTin Not today... I'm have a lot of work.. :/ maybe later I will send you my script that works for me.